# Exec Family Usage in C

Tags: c, linux, exec

I am beginner in C language. I have a question and the question is only about my curiosity. I have done a task recently. The fallowing code calculates time of process between parent and child. I am taking command 
like `ls,pwd` etc. via input. As a sample, while the code calculates time of `-ls` command, it does not calculate `ls -l`. I know I need to change `execlp` but I do not know which one is better according to that exec family ? In other words, How can I integrate true `exec()`  family type to my code ? Could you help me ?

My example output for  `ls` :

> ls
>   a.out  main.c
>   2006152 ms

My output for `ls -l`:

> ls -l
>   Error exec: No such file or directory

My codes :

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define N 20

void ChildProcess();    
void ParentProcess();    

struct timeval start, end;
char *input;
int main (int argc,char **argv) {
    input = argv[1];
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        ChildProcess ();
    }
    else {
        wait (NULL);
        ParentProcess ();
    }

    return 0;
}

void ChildProcess () {
    /* the size (in bytes) of shared memory object */
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    /* name of the shared memory object */
    const char* name = "OS";
    /* shared memory file descriptor */
    int shm_fd;
    /* pointer to shared memory obect */
    long int* ptr;
    /* create the shared memory object */
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    /* configure the size of the shared memory object */
    ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
    /* memory map the shared memory object */
    ptr =(long int*)mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    printf("%ld ",start.tv_usec);
    *ptr=start.tv_usec;
    if (execlp (input, "", (char *) 0) < 0)
    {
        perror ("Error exec");
        exit (0);}
    }
}

void ParentProcess () {
    /* the size (in bytes) of shared memory object */
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    /* name of the shared memory object */
    const char* name = "OS";
    /* shared memory file descriptor */
    int shm_fd;
    /* pointer to shared memory object */
    long int* ptr;
    /* open the shared memory object */
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDONLY, 0666);
    /* memory map the shared memory object */
    ptr =(long int*)mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    /* read from the shared memory object */
    printf("%ld usec okunan\n ", *ptr);
    long int start_usec = *ptr;
    /* remove the shared memory object */
    shm_unlink(name);
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    printf("%ld son : ",end.tv_usec);
    printf ("Total time : %ld %s dir \n", end.tv_usec-start_usec, "ms");
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should learn is to indent your code properly.

Comment: The problem is that the command is `ls` and it has `-l` as the argument. You absolutely cannot use `execl*` functions then for user-parsed input, you *must* use `execvp*`, and not anything else, for this case. There is no doubt.

Comment: The `exec*()` family of functions does not work like `system()`. Separate arguments on the command line need to be actually separate arguments to the function invocation, not a single string separated by spaces. I suggest you consult the man page for `execlp` again.

Comment: Seems like a job better suited to bash (or another scripting language) than C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are responsible for writing code to split up the input string up into separate arguments that you can pass to `execvp`:

```
/* Take your string "ls -l" and split it up into an array like this: */
char* split[3];
split[0] = "ls";
split[1] = "-l";
split[2] = NULL;
execvp(split[0], split);
```

If you don't know how to split strings in C to make this happen, you will have to research and learn that separately.

Alternatively, you can ask a shell to do it for you. However, this will also measure the startup and processing time of the shell:

```
char* command = "ls -l";
execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I did it and the code works as I want.